# How to split a column in Excel till the first number after *

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to split the **I have** range into **2**. The result i am wanting is till first number after `*`. I have tried to do text to columns and tried using Textbefore and textafter but it did not work because of the difference in length. There is where I am struggling.

| I have | I need | I need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC*K*1234*456 | ABC*K*1234 | 456 |
| AB*L2*987*456*459*326 | AB*L2*987 | 456*459*326 |
| AB*BCD*EFGJKL*DEG*22*1971 | AB*BCD*EFGJKL*DEG*22 | 1971 |
| GHI*FG*HIGUI*02*1971*1985 | GHI*FG*HIGUI*02 | 1971*1985 |

formula one

`=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"*",2)`

formula two

`=TEXTAFTER(A1,"*",3)`

Don't know why the * are removed from the markdown table. screen-print in excel. Ignore the spaces in between, markdown was not reading while there were no spaces.

[image]

Comment: @JvdV Please put your edit description in the revision reason field (which is designed for this information) instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Formula**:

Here is one option *without* `LAMBDA()`:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(s,A2:A5,z,"*",x,FILTERXML("<t><s>*"&SUBSTITUTE(s,z,"</s><s>*")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(.,2)*0=0][1]"),y,TEXTAFTER(s,x&z,1),IF({1,0},TEXTBEFORE(s,z&y),y))
```

The idea here is that `FILTERXML()`'s xpath expression is used to identify the position of the 1st number with `//s[substring(.,2)*0=0][1]`.

To prevent removal of leading zero's I inserted the asterisk at position 1 in every element first. This becomes also relevant when looking to use `TEXTBEFORE()` and `TEXTAFTER()` later on to prevent false positives.

**Note**: Using `FILTERXML()` in this context would require you to use the windows Excel 365 version.

---

**PowerQuery:**

Just for fun I played around in PQ to see if I could do this:

[image]

M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Out_1 = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{"I have", each let x = "*"&List.First(List.Select(Text.Split(_,"*"),(s)=> Text.Select(s,{"0".."9"})=s))&"*" in Text.ReplaceRange(_,Text.PositionOf(_,x)+Text.Length(x)-1,1,"|")}),
    Out_2 = Table.SplitColumn(Out_1, "I have", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"I need.1", "I need.2"})
in
    Out_2
```

Comment: By the way, cool that FILTERXML apparently allows 2D spill results unlike many functions within Excel

Answer (score 5):

Here's another method:

- Split on the `*`
- Using `XMATCH` find the first sequence of digits
- Using `TAKE` and `DROP`, create the sequences and `TEXTJOIN` with the `*` up to and after the first number
- `HSTACK` the two strings

```
B1: =LET(
    a, TEXTSPLIT(A1, "*"),
    b, XMATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(-a)),
    c, TEXTJOIN("*", , TAKE(a, , b)),
    d, TEXTJOIN("*", , DROP(a, , b)),
    HSTACK(c, d)
)
```

***and fill down***

[image]

*Note that certain values are converted to numbers by excel. These include values that your system may interpret as dates, exponential notation, ratios or fractions, etc. (eg: `May25`; 1E5; 5/9`). If these might be in your strings, and you want them interpreted as text, kindly expand your example to include them*

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A1:A4,
    κ,"*",
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ζ),2,
        LAMBDA(α,β,
            LET(
                ξ,INDEX(ζ,α,1),
                φ,XMATCH(1,1-ISERR(0+(TEXTSPLIT(ξ,κ)&"**0"))),
                IF(1-β,TEXTAFTER(ξ,κ,φ),TEXTBEFORE(ξ,κ,φ))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Before and After

```
=LET(data,A2:A10,dl,"*",e,"",
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
    LET(d,INDEX(data,r,1),
        ts,TEXTSPLIT(d,,dl),
        s,SEQUENCE(XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--ts))),
        tj,TEXTJOIN(dl,FALSE,INDEX(ts,s)),
    IFERROR(IF(c=1,tj,TEXTAFTER(d,tj&dl)),e)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Careful with checking for numericalness. If `A2` contained `ABC * 23 MAY * 1234 * 456`, for example, your current set-up would consider the substring `23 MAY` as a numeric after coercion, at least for English-language versions of Excel. This is why I appended the substring `"**0"` in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```
=LET(b,TEXTJOIN("*",1,DROP(TOROW(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,"*"),3),,1)),
     a,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(b)-1),
HSTACK(a,b))
```

Where it calculates the second part 'b' first by splitting the range by delimiter `*` and converting all spilled values into numeric. Text values will convert into error and are filtered out by the TOROW argument `3`.
Than `a` is calculated by removing the text string of `a` from the initial text.

and to spill it:

```
=DROP( REDUCE(0, A1:A4,
       LAMBDA(x, y,
              LET(b,TEXTJOIN("*",1,DROP(TOROW(--TEXTSPLIT(y,"*"),3),,1)),
                  a,LEFT(y,LEN(y)-LEN(b)-1),
VSTACK(x,
       HSTACK(a,b))))),
      1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SEARCH` to find the position of the asterisk. Then combine it with `LEFT` or `RIGHT` to get the substring that you want.

For example

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("*",A2)-1)
```

Comment: `SEARCH` allows wildcards, one of which is the asterisk. So as it stands, the `SEARCH` part of your formula will always return 1, since it is looking for the position of the first character which is of any length. To search for a literal asterisk, you need to include a tilde, i.e. `=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("~*",A2)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, you have a valid point here: as far as I know, Excel doesn't have a basic function to find the last entry of a substring within a string (but VBA does, it's the `InStrRev` function).

So, I would advise you to make a small function out of this `InStrRev` VBA function and use it in your Excel sheet, something like this:

VBA code:

```
Function LastIndexOf(inputstring As String, substring As String)
  LastIndexOf = InStrRev(inputstring, substring)
End Function
```

Excel formulae:

- Cell "B1" : `=LastIndexOf(A1,"_")`
- Cell "C1" : `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LastIndexOf(A1, "_"))`

(Cell "B1" is just for demonstration purposes.)

Screenshot:

[image]